# Create childrens in forEach

Tags: javascript, angular

permissions=["create:users", "read:profile", "read:roles", "read:users", "update:users", "write:messages"];

in that function I generate an array of objects, which will be my menu items

```
this.permissions.forEach(item => {
        const name = item.split(':')[1];
        const newItem: NbMenuItem = {
          title: name.toUpperCase(),
          link: '/' + name,
          icon: 'plus-square-outline'
        };
        items.push(newItem);
      });
```

that function returns

```
0: {title: "USERS", link: "/users", icon: "plus-square-outline", pathMatch: "full"}
1: {title: "PROFILE", link: "/profile", icon: "plus-square-outline", pathMatch: "full"}
2: {title: "ROLES", link: "/roles", icon: "plus-square-outline", pathMatch: "full"}
3: {title: "USERS", link: "/users", icon: "plus-square-outline", pathMatch: "full"}
4: {title: "USERS", link: "/users", icon: "plus-square-outline", pathMatch: "full"}
5: {title: "MESSAGES", link: "/messages", icon: "plus-square-outline", pathMatch: "full"}
```

how can I make it so that when several actions for a route come, in that array it comes:

```
create:user
update:user
read:user
```

how can I make it so that when several actions for a route come, example in that array comes:

```
{title: 'Users', icon: 'edit-2-outline', 
children: [
      {
      title: 'Create users',
      link: '/pages/forms/inputs',
      },
      {
      title: 'Update users',
      link: '/pages/forms/inputs',
      },
      {
      title: ' Read users',
      link: '/pages/forms/inputs',
      },
]
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `forEach` loop you can build one object with `keys` as name (group by) and values. If same key repeat (say 'USERS'), then push to their children. At the end of loop just get `Object.values` to get the array of objects built.

```js
const permissions = [
  "create:users",
  "read:profile",
  "read:roles",
  "read:users",
  "update:users",
  "write:messages"
];

const itemsObj = {};

permissions.forEach(item => {
  const [action, name] = item.split(":");
  const newItem = {
    title: name.toUpperCase(),
    icon: "plus-square-outline",
    children: [
      {
        title: `${action} ${name}`,
        link: "/" + name
      }
    ]
  };
  itemsObj[name] =
    name in itemsObj
      ? {
          ...itemsObj[name],
          children: [...itemsObj[name].children,
          ...newItem.children]
        }
      : newItem;
});

const items = Object.values(itemsObj);

console.log(items);
```